# How to determine if all my values in a column are null?

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

Using LINQ to SQL, how do I determine if all the values in a column are null so that I can trigger a certain action based off that?

I have a section of the program that can assign or unassign entire projects to a designer, or I can break the project into smaller shipments and assign/unassign those individually. I have two different tables that show unassigned projects and another that shows unassigned shipments. I need to figure out how to get a project to show up on the unassigned project table if all of its shipments have been individually unassigned.

What I tried was...

```
    If Not IsNothing(dgvAssignments.SelectedItem) Then

        Dim Count As Integer
        Dim DesignerNull As Integer

        SelectedProjectID = dgvAssignments.SelectedItem.ProjectID
        SelectedShipID = dgvAssignments.SelectedItem.Id

        Count = (From Shipment In db.Shipments
                 Where Shipment.ProjectID = SelectedProjectID
                 Select Shipment.ID).Count

        For i As Integer = 0 To Count - 1
            DesignerNull = (From Shipment In db.Shipments
                            Where Shipment.ProjectID = SelectedProjectID
                            Select Shipment.DesignerID).ToList(i)

        Next
        Do Until DesignerNull <> Nothing
            Dim UpdateProjectDesigner = (From Project In db.Projects
                                         Where Project.ID = SelectedProjectID
                                         Select Project)
            For Each Project As Project In UpdateProjectDesigner
                Project.DesignerID = Nothing
            Next
        Loop
    End If
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: The portion where DesignerNull is being defined throws an exception saying that a Nullable object must have a value.

Comment: Do you have `Option Strict On` set?

Comment: It was set to On. I tried switching it to off and I still get the same exception.

Comment: Don't ever switch it off. Where's the `.ToList(i)` extension coming from?

Comment: Is it `Shipment.ProjectID` that is nullable?  If so then you have to first make sure that there is a value before getting it and comparing it to something else.  That would mean that `Where Shipment.ProjectID = SelectedProjectID` becomes `Where Shipment.ProjectID.HasValue AndAlso Shipment.ProjectID = SelectedProjectID`.

Comment: No, it's the DesignerID that is nullable.

Comment: The .ToList(i) is putting all the DesignerIDs in a list so that I'm able to look at the values. It's the designerID that I need to check if all the values are null or not.